# bootstrap: how to pass text value to button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two form fields.if clicked the text from `<div class="offer-text"> RS.750/- </div>` the  `RS.750/-` could be appear in the button. since I am new to bootstrap. Can anyone help me to do this?

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">         
    <form  method="POST" action="information.php">
      <div class="">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-block"/>SEND</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form2"> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="offer-text"> RS.750/- </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

Comment: You want RS.760 to replace the word SEND`?

Comment: ya. that what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the value to the form button use the following code:

```
$(".offer-text").click(function() {
  $("form button[type=submit]").text($(this).text())
})
```

**demo**

```js
$(".offer-text").click(function() {
  $("form button[type=submit]").text($(this).text())
})

$("img").click(function() {
  $("form button[type=submit]").text($(this).attr("value"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form method="POST" action="information.php">
      <div class="">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-block" />SEND</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-3"> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="offer-text"> RS.750/- </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>

<img src="img/Sar Utha Kay Jeo.png" alt="IMG" style="width:100%" value="RS.1750/-" class="hover-shadow cursor">
```

Comment: brother is there any way to show the img value to that button?

Comment: <img src="img/Sar Utha Kay Jeo.png"   style="width:100%" value="RS.1750/-"  class="hover-shadow cursor"> if i used img instead of the text..

Comment: I´ve opdated the snippet